# How to add my current address to a paper?

Tags: amsart, addresses

I use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
```

and I want to add my current address to the paper while keeping the old address where the work was finished.

Hence, I wrote:

```
\author{Name}
\address{University A, Department of Mathematics} \email{name@A.math.edu}

\address{University B, Department of Mathematics} \email{name@B.math.edu}
```

How to add a text **current address** in between to show the second address is my current address?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`amsart` provides the command `\curraddr` for precisely the purpose of identifying
an author's current address.

Like other addresses, it will be placed at the end of the article in this order

- address from which the article was submitted
- current address, introduced by `{\itshape Current address}:`
- email address, introduced by `{\itshape E-mail address}:`
- url, introduced by `{\itshape URL}:`